# Display image in a datatable

Tags: image, datatables

I have a datatable which should display an image in the first column.
I do it as follows :

```
    var datatable = $("#detail-logs").DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "searching": true,
        "info": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12'p>>",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("SearchProcessDetails", "Logs", new { id= Request.QueryString["id"] })",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            // "deferLoading": 0,
            "columns": [
                { "name": "@Constants.ProcessDetailColumnNames.Status", render: getImg},
                { "name": "@Constants.ProcessDetailColumnNames.Entity" },
                ...
            ]
        });

        function getImg(data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<img src="~/Content/images/check.png" alt="Check"/>';
        }
```

However it doesn't display my image. I get the error that the image cannot be found.
In the HTML I see : 
Which is correct.

However when I check the error, it says that the image "http://localhost:56139/nl/Logs/~/Content/images/check.png" cannot be found.
Which is logic, because the correct link is "http://localhost:56139/Content/images/check.png"

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "~/Content/images/check.png" to "../../Content/images/check.png" and now it works perfectly.